# Convert Variable Name to String?

Tags: python, string, variables

I would like to convert a python variable name into the string equivalent as shown. Any ideas how?

```
var = {}
print ???  # Would like to see 'var'
something_else = 3
print ???  # Would print 'something_else'
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you're trying to achieve? It seems like you're asking how to solve a problem the wrong way. Also, there's a similar question, but about Ruby http://stackoverflow.com/questions/58482/ruby-get-a-variables-name

Comment: I checked this question because, using RPy2, I want to pass a Python variable with an eponymous R name.  A useless (but close to my application) example: `def to_R( py_var ): r.assign( 'py_var', py_var )` to assign the data in (Py) py_var to the R environment and have the same name.  It'd be useful for me to do instead, `r.assign( py_var.stringof, py_var )` a la [D](http://dlang.org/property.html) since the variable name passed to my fn `to_r` is not necessarily `py_var`.

Comment: One way to make use of this is when an Assert statement fails. You could provide the user with the exact variable name in question while keeping your code generic e.g. AssertionError: 'something_else' must be a number greater than 5.  You could then test every variable that needs to be greater than 5, and get the variable name in the AssertionError message.

Comment: Thank goodness there is a question about how to do this in Ruby!

Answer (score 65, accepted):

#### TL;DR: Not possible. See 'conclusion' at the end.

---

There is an usage scenario where you might need this. I'm not implying there are not better ways or achieving the same functionality.

This would be useful in order to 'dump' an arbitrary list of dictionaries in case of error, in debug modes and other similar situations.

What would be needed, is the reverse of the `eval()` function:

```
get_indentifier_name_missing_function()
```

which would take an identifier name ('variable','dictionary',etc) as an argument, and return a
string containing the identifier’s name.

---

Consider the following current state of affairs:

```
random_function(argument_data)
```

If one is passing an identifier name ('function','variable','dictionary',etc) `argument_data` to a `random_function()` (another identifier name), one actually passes an identifier (e.g.: `<argument_data object at 0xb1ce10>`) to another identifier  (e.g.: `<function random_function at 0xafff78>`):

```
<function random_function at 0xafff78>(<argument_data object at 0xb1ce10>)
```

From my understanding, only the memory address is passed to the function:

```
<function at 0xafff78>(<object at 0xb1ce10>)
```

Therefore, one would need to pass a string as an argument to `random_function()` in order for that function to have the argument's identifier name:

```
random_function('argument_data')
```

Inside the random_function()

```
def random_function(first_argument):
```

, one would use the already supplied string `'argument_data'` to:

1. serve as an 'identifier name' (to display, log, string split/concat, whatever)
2. feed the `eval()` function in order to get a reference to the actual identifier, and therefore, a reference to the real data:

   ```
   print("Currently working on", first_argument)
   some_internal_var = eval(first_argument)
   print("here comes the data: " + str(some_internal_var))
   ```

Unfortunately, this doesn't work in all cases. It only works if the `random_function()` can resolve the `'argument_data'` string to an actual identifier. I.e. If `argument_data` identifier name is available in the `random_function()`'s namespace.

This isn't always the case:

```
# main1.py
import some_module1

argument_data = 'my data'

some_module1.random_function('argument_data')


# some_module1.py
def random_function(first_argument):
    print("Currently working on", first_argument)
    some_internal_var = eval(first_argument)
    print("here comes the data: " + str(some_internal_var))
######
```

Expected results would be:

```
Currently working on: argument_data
here comes the data: my data
```

Because `argument_data` identifier name is not available in the `random_function()`'s namespace, this would yield instead:

```
Currently working on argument_data
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "~/main1.py", line 6, in <module>
    some_module1.random_function('argument_data')
  File "~/some_module1.py", line 4, in random_function
    some_internal_var = eval(first_argument)
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'argument_data' is not defined
```

---

Now, consider the hypotetical usage of a `get_indentifier_name_missing_function()` which would behave as described above.

Here's a dummy Python 3.0 code: .

```
# main2.py
import some_module2
some_dictionary_1       = { 'definition_1':'text_1',
                            'definition_2':'text_2',
                            'etc':'etc.' }
some_other_dictionary_2 = { 'key_3':'value_3',
                            'key_4':'value_4', 
                            'etc':'etc.' }
#
# more such stuff
#
some_other_dictionary_n = { 'random_n':'random_n',
                            'etc':'etc.' }

for each_one_of_my_dictionaries in ( some_dictionary_1,
                                     some_other_dictionary_2,
                                     ...,
                                     some_other_dictionary_n ):
    some_module2.some_function(each_one_of_my_dictionaries)


# some_module2.py
def some_function(a_dictionary_object):
    for _key, _value in a_dictionary_object.items():
        print( get_indentifier_name_missing_function(a_dictionary_object)    +
               "    " +
               str(_key) +
               "  =  " +
               str(_value) )
######
```

Expected results would be:

```
some_dictionary_1    definition_1  =  text_1
some_dictionary_1    definition_2  =  text_2
some_dictionary_1    etc  =  etc.
some_other_dictionary_2    key_3  =  value_3
some_other_dictionary_2    key_4  =  value_4
some_other_dictionary_2    etc  =  etc.
......
......
......
some_other_dictionary_n    random_n  =  random_n
some_other_dictionary_n    etc  =  etc.
```

Unfortunately, `get_indentifier_name_missing_function()` would not see the 'original' identifier names (`some_dictionary_`,`some_other_dictionary_2`,`some_other_dictionary_n`). It would only see the `a_dictionary_object` identifier name.

Therefore the real result would rather be:

```
a_dictionary_object    definition_1  =  text_1
a_dictionary_object    definition_2  =  text_2
a_dictionary_object    etc  =  etc.
a_dictionary_object    key_3  =  value_3
a_dictionary_object    key_4  =  value_4
a_dictionary_object    etc  =  etc.
......
......
......
a_dictionary_object    random_n  =  random_n
a_dictionary_object    etc  =  etc.
```

So, the reverse of the `eval()` function won't be that useful in this case.

---

Currently, one would need to do this:

```
# main2.py same as above, except:

    for each_one_of_my_dictionaries_names in ( 'some_dictionary_1',
                                               'some_other_dictionary_2',
                                               '...',
                                               'some_other_dictionary_n' ):
        some_module2.some_function( { each_one_of_my_dictionaries_names :
                                     eval(each_one_of_my_dictionaries_names) } )
    
    
    # some_module2.py
    def some_function(a_dictionary_name_object_container):
        for _dictionary_name, _dictionary_object in a_dictionary_name_object_container.items():
            for _key, _value in _dictionary_object.items():
                print( str(_dictionary_name) +
                       "    " +
                       str(_key) +
                       "  =  " +
                       str(_value) )
    ######
```

---

### In conclusion:

- Python passes only memory addresses as arguments to functions.
- Strings representing the name of an identifier, can only be referenced back to the actual identifier by the `eval()` function if the name identifier is available in the current namespace.
- A hypothetical reverse of the `eval()` function, would not be useful in cases where the identifier name is not 'seen' directly by the calling code. E.g. inside any called function.
- Currently one needs to pass to a function:

  1. the string representing the identifier name
  2. the actual identifier (memory address)

This can be achieved by passing both the `'string'` and `eval('string')` to the called function at the same time. I think this is the most 'general' way of solving this egg-chicken problem across arbitrary functions, modules, namespaces, without using corner-case solutions. The only downside is the use of the `eval()` function which may easily lead to unsecured code. Care must be taken to not feed the `eval()` function with just about anything, especially unfiltered external-input data.

Comment: This is an outstanding write-up, and the kind of high-quality content I come here for.

Comment: There is something not right in Python if to obtain the name of an object we need a 5 pages answer on StackOverflow. :/

Comment: A tl;dr would be nice.

Comment: @Nimitz14 Included TL;DR. Feel free to propose edits, corrections.

Comment: the TLDR states that it's not possible to achieve what has been asked by the OP.
Yet, the answer of @Alice and other similar answers in which the use of locals() or globals() is suggested achieve exactly that.  So this TLDR is misleading and this should not be the accepted answer.

Comment: @seymour i wrote a `varname` function below that actually answers the question.   imo: this is a missing feature from python.  i explained why.   this accepted answer is miselading.

Comment: There are a number of languages that provide that functionality - even C/C++ compiled to machine-language can via defines; Python boasts as easy to use entry point for programming but lacks such a popular tool for people to learn and see what their program is doing;
Like C/C++, a "compile-time" function could do the job perfectly but it seems all suggested methods of trying to locate a variable name in globals() or etc is only partially successful and cannot work 100% of the time. Matching is done on the objects that multiple variables could reference.

Answer (score 60):

**Totally possible with the python-varname package (python3):**

```
from varname import nameof

s = 'Hey!'

print (nameof(s))
```

Output:

```
s
```

Install:

```
pip3 install varname
```

Or get the package here:

https://github.com/pwwang/python-varname

Comment: What if I want a function that takes input that changes and prints the input variable's name? For example def somefunction(a): nameof(a). Then somefunction(dtar) prints dtar and somefunction(rat) prints rat. etc.

Comment: I have been scouring the internet for an answer like this. Thank you @synthase !

Comment: @rsc05, I think what you would need is `from varname import argname` as shown in the examples on their GitHub [page](https://github.com/pwwang/python-varname).

Comment: This is useful in Django, as many times you need to pass the model field names as strings, but strings can't be easily renamed. Using this, one can take advantage of refactoring tools to simply rename the model field, and everything would be updated.

Answer (score 15):

as long as it's a variable and not a second class, this here works for me:

```
def print_var_name(variable):
 for name in globals():
     if eval(name) == variable:
        print name
foo = 123
print_var_name(foo)
>>>foo
```

this happens for class members:

```
class xyz:
     def __init__(self):
         pass
member = xyz()
print_var_name(member)
>>>member
```

ans this for classes (as example):

```
abc = xyz
print_var_name(abc)
>>>abc
>>>xyz
```

So for classes it gives you the name AND the properteries

Comment: Please [edit] your post for formatting issues. It is difficult to understand what you are saying.

Comment: It is a real pleasure to read a post that answers the question without ranting about why the question is being asked.

Comment: Note that it's possible to have the same value bound to multiple names.  In this case, the above code will print multiple names.  There is no way to know which name is the "correct" one.

Comment: use `is variable` not `== variable` ... safer

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to work in python 3 anymore. Changing `print name` to `print(name)` is quite obvious, but it still errors out. @Erik Aronesty's fix gets it to work, but the issue @steveha points out, still remains.

Answer (score 14):

I searched for this question because I wanted a Python program to print assignment statements for some of the variables in the program. For example, it might print "foo = 3, bar = 21, baz = 432". The print function would need the variable names in string form. I could have provided my code with the strings "foo","bar", and "baz", but that felt like repeating myself. After reading the previous answers, I developed the solution below.

The globals() function behaves like a dict with variable names (in the form of strings) as keys. I wanted to retrieve from globals() the key corresponding to the value of each variable. The method globals().items() returns a list of tuples; in each tuple the first item is the variable name (as a string) and the second is the variable value. My variablename() function searches through that list to find the variable name(s) that corresponds to the value of the variable whose name I need in string form.

The function itertools.ifilter() does the search by testing each tuple in the globals().items() list with the function `lambda x: var is globals()[x[0]]`. In that function x is the tuple being tested; x[0] is the variable name (as a string) and x[1] is the value. The lambda function tests whether the value of the tested variable is the same as the value of the variable passed to variablename(). In fact, by using the `is` operator, the lambda function tests whether the name of the tested variable is bound to the exact same object as the variable passed to variablename(). If so, the tuple passes the test and is returned by ifilter().

The itertools.ifilter() function actually returns an iterator which doesn't return any results until it is called properly. To get it called properly, I put it inside a list comprehension `[tpl[0] for tpl ... globals().items())]`. The list comprehension saves only the variable name `tpl[0]`, ignoring the variable value. The list that is created contains one or more names (as strings) that are bound to the value of the variable passed to variablename().

In the uses of variablename() shown below, the desired string is returned as an element in a list. In many cases, it will be the only item in the list. If another variable name is assigned the same value, however, the list will be longer.

```
>>> def variablename(var):
...     import itertools
...     return [tpl[0] for tpl in 
...     itertools.ifilter(lambda x: var is x[1], globals().items())]
... 
>>> var = {}
>>> variablename(var)
['var']
>>> something_else = 3
>>> variablename(something_else)
['something_else']
>>> yet_another = 3
>>> variablename(something_else)
['yet_another', 'something_else']
```

---

`itertools.ifilter()` was removed in Python 3 because the built-in `filter()` function provides the same functionality now.

Answer (score 7):

This is not possible.

In Python, there really isn't any such thing as a "variable".  What Python really has are "names" which can have objects bound to them.  It makes no difference to the object what names, if any, it might be bound to.  It might be bound to dozens of different names, or none.

Consider this example:

```
foo = 1
bar = 1
baz = 1
```

Now, suppose you have the integer object with value 1, and you want to work backwards and find its name.  What would you print?  Three different names have that object bound to them, and all are equally valid.

In Python, a name is a way to access an object, so there is no way to work with names directly.  There might be some clever way to hack the Python bytecodes or something to get the value of the name, but that is at best a parlor trick.

If you know you want `print foo` to print `"foo"`, you might as well just execute `print "foo"` in the first place.

EDIT: I have changed the wording slightly to make this more clear.  Also, here is an even better example:

```
foo = 1
bar = foo
baz = foo
```

In practice, Python reuses the same object for integers with common values like 0 or 1, so the first example should bind the same object to all three names.  But this example is crystal clear: the same object is bound to foo, bar, and baz.

Comment: objects don't have names, names have objects

Comment: There is a way to work with these names, the globals() dict, but it's not clear how to use that to do what the OP asked.

Comment: of course, *it is possible*. and quite trivial at that (it solves the OP's problem, anyway). it's just something no one should want to do.

Comment: you say it's not possible. Yet is possible. See other answers. 
@SilentGhost: may you clarify why "no one should want to do it"? I guess it depends on the application. What's your argument?

Comment: @Robyc You say "Yet is possible."  Okay.  I gave examples binding `foo` `bar` and `baz` all to `1`.  Then what's "the name" of `1`?  If you look through all the globals you could return a list of variable names: `['foo', 'bar', 'baz']` (in some random order).  Okay.  What is the use of this list?  Is one of the names the "true" name of `1`?  (No.)  Those of us who are saying "it" is not possible all agree that you could look through globals and find all the names; we just don't think that's a useful thing to do.  As I said: an object "might be bound to dozens of different names, or none."

Comment: @Robyc  You also said "I guess it depends on the application."  Okay.  Please tell me an example of some case where it would be useful to have the ability to look through globals and find all the variable names that have a given object reference bound to them.  I'm not aware of one, but if you have one, I'm quite interested; please share it with us.

Comment: I defines a bunch of variable "names" (they can point to the same value, it doesn't matter) that are used to do some processing. Then I want to save the results of my processing writing in the filename the "name" of the variable I used for that specific result, so to keep track of what is what. E.g. `var1=10  ==> result1 = some_processing(var1) ==> out_file_1 = 'some_result_using_var1.png'`.  Of course you can do that with a dictionary, for example: `var1 = {"var1" : 10}`  and is maybe a more pythonic way to do it.

Comment: @Robyc  If you are working with a bunch of names, it is definitely best practice to keep a list or dictionary of the names and use that to look them up again, and not to try to look through the globals and hope to recover the names later.

Comment: Agreed. After trying the "globals()" way it became apparent that having a dictionary is a much better way to achieve my goal (as I also stated in my prev comment). Again, and sorry if I'm picky, you shouldn't write that "it's not possible" if it actually is, hence my critique. You can write "it's highly not advisable in all cases I can think of" :)

Comment: @Robyc The original question was to recover the name of a variable.  That really is "not possible": you can't start with a value and find "the" name.  You _can_ go through globals and make a list of all names that currently have that value bound to them, and if there is only one name in the list then I guess you found "the" name; but the basic premise of the question was flawed and I don't think it was wrong to try to educate the person who asked the question on how things actually work.  A value could be bound to dozens of names, or none.

Answer (score 6):

Technically the information is available to you, but as others have asked, how would you make use of it in a sensible way?

```
>>> x = 52
>>> globals()
{'__builtins__': <module '__builtin__' (built-in)>, '__name__': '__main__', 
'x': 52, '__doc__': None, '__package__': None}
```

This shows that the variable name is present as a string in the globals() dictionary.

```
>>> globals().keys()[2]
'x'
```

In this case it happens to be the third key, but there's no reliable way to know where a given variable name will end up

```
>>> for k in globals().keys():
...   if not k.startswith("_"):
...     print k
...
x
>>>
```

You could filter out system variables like this, but you're still going to get all of your own items. Just running that code above created another variable "k" that changed the position of "x" in the dict.

But maybe this is a useful start for you. If you tell us what you want this capability for, more helpful information could possibly be given.

Comment: Chris, your comment doesn't seem to relate to my answer or the original question. Who are you scolding and why? You don't know if he's writing production code or just experimenting with language features for his own education.

Answer (score 3):

What are you trying to achieve? There is absolutely no reason to ever do what you describe, and there is likely a much better solution to the problem you're trying to solve..

The most obvious alternative to what you request is a dictionary. For example:

```
>>> my_data = {'var': 'something'}
>>> my_data['something_else'] = 'something'
>>> print my_data.keys()
['var', 'something_else']
>>> print my_data['var']
something
```

Mostly as a.. challenge, I implemented your desired output. Do not use this code, please!

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2.6
class NewLocals:
    """Please don't ever use this code.."""
    def __init__(self, initial_locals):
        self.prev_locals = list(initial_locals.keys())

    def show_new(self, new_locals):
        output = ", ".join(list(set(new_locals) - set(self.prev_locals)))
        self.prev_locals = list(new_locals.keys())
        return output
# Set up
eww = None
eww = NewLocals(locals())

# "Working" requested code

var = {}

print eww.show_new(locals())  # Outputs: var

something_else = 3
print eww.show_new(locals()) # Outputs: something_else

# Further testing

another_variable = 4
and_a_final_one = 5

print eww.show_new(locals()) # Outputs: another_variable, and_a_final_one
```

Comment: This is pretty cool, but quite as automatic as I would like. Thanks for the tip =]

Comment: "There is absolutely no reason to ever do what you describe" - We have a local all-knowing entity here. There are actually some good usecases for this.

Answer (score 3):

By using the  the **unpacking operator**:

```
>>> def tostr(**kwargs):
    return kwargs

>>> var = {}
>>> something_else = 3
>>> tostr(var = var,something_else=something_else)
{'var' = {},'something_else'=3}
```

Comment: Thanks @restrepo, this was exactly what I needed to create a standard save_df_to_file() function. For this, I made some small changes to your tostr() function:

`
    def variabletostr(**df):
        variablename = list(df.keys())[0]
        return variablename
    
    variabletostr(df=0)
`

FYI: I added this code as a new post in this thread

Answer (score 3):

### Possible for Python >= 3.8  (with f'{var=}' string )

Not sure if this could be used in production code, but in Python 3.8(and up) you can **use f' string debugging specifier.** Add = at the end of an expression, and it will print both the expression and its value:

```
my_salary_variable = 5000
print(f'{my_salary_variable  =  }')

Output:
my_salary_variable  =  5000
```

To uncover this magic here is another example:

```
param_list = f'{my_salary_variable=}'.split('=')
print(param_list)

Output:
['my_salary_variable', '5000']
```

**Explanation: when you put '=' after your var in f'string, it returns a string with variable name, '=' and its value. Split it with .split('=') and get a List of 2 strings, [0] - your_variable_name, and [1] - actual object of variable.**
Pick up [0] element of the list if you need variable name only.

```
my_salary_variable = 5000
param_list = f'{my_salary_variable=}'.split('=')
print(param_list[0])
Output:
my_salary_variable

or, in one line

my_salary_variable = 5000
print(f'{my_salary_variable=}'.split('=')[0])
Output:
my_salary_variable
```

**Works with functions too:**

```
def my_super_calc_foo(number):
    return number**3

print(f'{my_super_calc_foo(5)  =  }')
print(f'{my_super_calc_foo(5)=}'.split('='))
```

**Output:**

```
my_super_calc_foo(5)  =  125
['my_super_calc_foo(5)', '125']

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Answer (score 2):

You somehow have to refer to the variable you want to print the name of. So it would look like:

```
print varname(something_else)
```

There is no such function, but if there were it would be kind of pointless. You have to type out `something_else`, so you can as well just type quotes to the left and right of it to print the name as a string:

```
print "something_else"
```

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer.

Comment: i created a `varname` function, below.  works for methods too.

Comment: This is wrong. I want to check the name of a variable in a loop! So, I cannot type it and it is not pointless!

Comment: sth didn't understand the question. Other languages support functions like varname. Python currently has no method to do this. Every who uses other languages uses this functionality all of the time. Idiomatic python is one thing, ignoring the question is another thing.

Answer (score 2):

Does Django not do this when generating field names?

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev//topics/db/models/#verbose-field-names

Seems reasonable to me.

Comment: I think in django models, fields are attributes of one class or instance, getting attribute names is not the same thing with converting variable name to string.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is a cool solution and I suppose the best you can get. But do you see any way to handle the ambigious results, your function may return?
As ["is" operator behaves unexpectedly with integers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/306313/python-is-operator-behaves-unexpectedly-with-integers) shows, low integers and strings of the same value get cached by python so that your variablename-function might priovide ambigous results with a high probability. 
In my case, I would like to create a decorator, that adds a  new variable to a class by the varialbename i pass it:

```
def inject(klass, dependency):
klass.__dict__["__"+variablename(dependency)]=dependency
```

But if your method returns ambigous results, how can I know the name of the variable I added?

```
var any_var="myvarcontent"
var myvar="myvarcontent"
@inject(myvar)
class myclasss():
    def myclass_method(self):
        print self.__myvar    #I can not be sure, that this variable will be set...
```

Maybe if I will also check the local list I could at least remove the "dependency"-Variable from the list, but this will not be a reliable result.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a succinct variation that lets you specify any directory.
The issue with using directories to find anything is that multiple variables can have the same value. So this code returns a list of possible variables.

```
def varname( var, dir=locals()):
  return [ key for key, val in dir.items() if id( val) == id( var)]
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't know it's right or not, but it worked for me

```
def varname(variable):
    for name in list(globals().keys()):
        expression = f'id({name})'
        if id(variable) == eval(expression):
            return name
```

Answer (score 2):

it is possible to a limited extent. the answer is similar to the solution by @tamtam .
The given example assumes the following assumptions -

- You are searching for a variable by its value
- The variable has a distinct value
- The value is in the global namespace

Example:

```
testVar         = "unique value"
varNameAsString = [k for k,v in globals().items() if v == "unique value"]
#
# the variable "varNameAsString" will contain all the variable name that matches
# the value "unique value"
# for this example, it will be a list of a single entry "testVar"
#
print(varNameAsString)
```

**Output : ['testVar']**

You can extend this example for any other variable/data type

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to point out a use case for this that is not an anti-pattern, and there is no better way to do it.

This seems to be a *missing* feature in python.

There are a number of functions, like `patch.object`, that take the name of a method or property to be patched or accessed.

Consider this:

`patch.object(obj, "method_name", new_reg)`

This can potentially start "false succeeding" when you change the name of a method.  IE: you can ship a bug, you thought you were testing.... simply because of a bad method name refactor.

Now consider:  `varname`.  This could be an efficient, built-in function.  But for now it can work by iterating an object or the caller's frame:

Now your call can be:

`patch.member(obj, obj.method_name, new_reg)`

And the patch function can call:

`varname(var, obj=obj)`

This would: assert that the var is bound to the obj and return the name of the member.  Or if the obj is not specified, use the callers stack frame to derive it, etc.

Could be made an efficient built in at some point, but here's a definition that works.   I deliberately didn't support **builtins**, easy to add tho:

Feel free to stick this in a package called `varname.py`, and use it in your patch.object calls:

`patch.object(obj, varname(obj, obj.method_name), new_reg)`

Note: this was written for python 3.

```py
import inspect

def _varname_dict(var, dct):
    key_name = None
    for key, val in dct.items():
        if val is var:
            if key_name is not None:
                raise NotImplementedError("Duplicate names not supported %s, %s" % (key_name, key))
            key_name = key
    return key_name

def _varname_obj(var, obj):
    key_name = None
    for key in dir(obj):
        val = getattr(obj, key)
        equal = val is var
        if equal:
            if key_name is not None:
                raise NotImplementedError("Duplicate names not supported %s, %s" % (key_name, key))
            key_name = key
    return key_name

def varname(var, obj=None):
    if obj is None:
        if hasattr(var, "__self__"):
            return var.__name__
        caller_frame = inspect.currentframe().f_back
        try:
            ret = _varname_dict(var, caller_frame.f_locals)
        except NameError:
            ret = _varname_dict(var, caller_frame.f_globals)
    else:
        ret = _varname_obj(var, obj)
    if ret is None:
        raise NameError("Name not found. (Note: builtins not supported)")
    return ret
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work for simnple data types (str, int, float, list etc.)

```
>>> def my_print(var_str) : 
      print var_str+':', globals()[var_str]
>>> a = 5
>>> b = ['hello', ',world!']
>>> my_print('a')
a: 5
>>> my_print('b')
b: ['hello', ',world!']
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not very Pythonesque but I was curious and found this solution. You need to duplicate the globals dictionary since its size will change as soon as you define a new variable.

```
def var_to_name(var):
    # noinspection PyTypeChecker
    dict_vars = dict(globals().items())

    var_string = None

    for name in dict_vars.keys():
        if dict_vars[name] is var:
            var_string = name
            break

    return var_string


if __name__ == "__main__":
    test = 3
    print(f"test = {test}")
    print(f"variable name: {var_to_name(test)}")
```

which returns:

```
test = 3
variable name: test
```

Comment: You are looking up the `globals` dict. This exact thing has been done in a previous answer without creating extra variables and using `itertools`. While the answer is good, I think since a similar solution has been provided, you should upvote that and avoid repetition.

Answer (score 0):

To get the variable name of `var` as a string:

```
var = 1000
var_name = [k for k,v in locals().items() if v == var][0] 
print(var_name) # ---> outputs 'var'
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @restrepo, this was exactly what I needed to create a standard save_df_to_file() function. For this, I made some small changes to your tostr() function. Hope this will help someone else:

```
def variabletostr(**df):
        variablename = list(df.keys())[0]
        return variablename
    
    variabletostr(df=0)
```

Answer (score 0):

The original question is pretty old, but I found an *almost* solution with Python 3. (I say almost because I think you can get close to a solution but I do not believe there is a solution concrete enough to satisfy the exact request).

First, you might want to consider the following:

- objects are a core concept in Python, and they may be assigned a variable, but the variable itself is a bound name (think pointer or reference) not the object itself
- `var` is just a variable name bound to an object and that object could have more than one reference (in your example it does not seem to)
- in this case, `var` appears to be in the global namespace so you can use the global `builtin` conveniently named `global`
- different name references to the same object will all share the same `id`  which can be checked by running the id `builtin` `id` like so: `id(var)`

This function grabs the global variables and filters out the ones matching the *content* of your variable.

```py
def get_bound_names(target_variable):
    '''Returns a list of bound object names.'''
    return [k for k, v in globals().items() if v is target_variable]
```

The real challenge here is that you are not guaranteed to get back the variable name by itself. It will be a list, but that list will contain the variable name you are looking for. If your target variable (bound to an object) is really the only bound name, you could access it this way:

```py
bound_names = get_variable_names(target_variable)
var_string = bound_names[0]
```

Answer (score -1):

This module works for converting variables names to a string:
https://pypi.org/project/varname/

Use it like this:

```py
from varname import nameof

variable=0

name=nameof(variable)

print(name)

//output: variable
```

Install it by:

```
pip install varname
```

Comment: This package is already mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65756509/3749896). (Btw: the  `!` is incorrect before `pip`).

Comment: Ya I noticed it was already mentioned after posting. You are right about the ´!´, I edited it. Was like that because I was on a notebook, only use ´!´ if you are on Jupyter.

Answer (score -4):

```
print "var"
print "something_else"
```

Or did you mean something_else?