# Get the name of a variable

Tags: python, variables

I would like to know if it's possible to get the name of the variable who call the function, and how.
For example :

```
myVar = something
myVar2 = something
myVar.function()
myVar2.function()
```

and the code should return

```
myVar calls function()
myVar2 calls function()
```

Thank you.

Comment: You might wanna take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1534504/convert-variable-name-to-string since this is possible copy of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make some stack manipulation to achieve that, but I certainly do not recommend doing it. Hope you never use it in real code:

```
>>> class C:
        def function(self):
            text = inspect.stack()[1][4][0].strip().split('.')
            return '{0} calls {1}'.format(*text)

>>> myVar = C()
>>> myVar.function()
'myVar calls function()'
```

Answer (score 3):

It seems like `something` is an object of a custom class already (if this is a built-in class, you can subclass it). Just add an instance attribute `name`, assign it when creating and use later:

```
In [1]: class MyClass:
   ...:     def __init__(self, name):
   ...:         self.name = name
   ...:     def function(self):
   ...:         print 'function called on', self.name
   ...: 

In [2]: myVar = MyClass('Joe')

In [3]: myVar2 = MyClass('Ben')

In [4]: myVar.function()
function called on Joe

In [5]: myVar2.function()
function called on Ben
```

P.S. I know this is not exactly what you are asking, but I think **this** is better than actually trying to use the variable name. The question mentioned in the comment above has a very nice [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3683258/1258041) explaining why.

Answer (score 1):

There might not be a name:

```
def another:
    return something 

another().function()
```

Lev's answer has the nice property that it does not depend on any internal python implementation details. Lev's technique is the one I usually use.

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
def myfuncname():
    pass
myvar=myfuncname
print globals()['myvar'].__name__
```

and it will print the name of the function the variable is assigned to.

Comment: What?!? `globals()['myvar']` is, barring shadowing by a local variable (which is not the case here), equal to just referencing `myvar`. Second, the `__name__` of a function is the name used during its definition (if it's not changed manually later on), so this will print `myfuncname`, not `myvar`, even if the variable `myfuncname` no longer exists or refers to something different. Third, this is not what the question asks for. -1