# Add variable name to variable

Tags: python, variables

I have the following variable:

```
VarX=700
```

I now need to write the name of `VarX` into a txt file. So I'm thinking I need to create another variable and assign to it the name of `VarX` and then write it to a file. How can I assign a name of a variable to a variable?

Comment: `data = {'VarX': 700}`

Comment: Search for "python list tutorial" or "python dict tutorial", perhaps. There are some fundamental concepts that should be explored independently.

Comment: This is what you need http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1534504/convert-variable-name-to-string

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you store your information as a dictionary:

```
variables = {'VarX': 700}
```

then you have access to the name and value without obfuscating your code.

Answer (score 1):

So you have a value, and you want to associate it with a name.  That's what we call a key/value pair, and in Python, you should use a `dict` (dictionary) to store that.

http://www.developer.com/lang/other/article.php/630721/Learn-to-Program-Using-Python-Getting-Started-with-Dictionaries.htm

I recommend you use JSON format to save it to disk.  You can put your key/value pairs into a dict, then save the whole dict to a JSON file.  It's easy and reliable.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4759634/python-json-tutorial