# python - show variables during traceback

Tags: python, django, debugging

I have created the following situation:

I have a cronjob that runs some python code and it crashes. Consider this code:

```
import json

uno = 1
print json.loads(uno)
```

I receive the following traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "thiswillbreak.py", line 4, in <module>
    print json.loads(uno)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 326, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 366, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
TypeError: expected string or buffer
```

Is there anyway for me to also receive a list of all the variables in the scope so that I can debug this on the fly instead of attempting to reproduce the scenario? Obviously hard-coded values are easy, but if this value is obtained from some other place - debugging gets harder.

In particular I'm also using Django, which I know has loggers, but I couldn't find any information on how to enable variable printing. I only found how to hide sensitive variables, which isn't a problem because I don't see *any* variables at all.

Comment: take a look at python's logging tutorial (http://docs.python.org/2/howto/logging.html) -- you won't get an automatic list of *every* variable in scope, but you can log specific variables with specific messages.

Answer (score 2):

As the best practice you should avoid dubug info in your output or exceptions, there are tools to help you with that. Here's an example:

[image]

Have a look at some related packages. For simple usage you might pick [traceback-with-variables](https://pypi.org/project/traceback-with-variables) (`pip install traceback-with-variables`), here is it's postcard

[image]

Or try [tbvaccine](https://pypi.org/project/tbvaccine/), or [better-exceptions](https://pypi.org/project/better-exceptions/), or [any other package](https://pypi.org/search/?q=print%20variables%20on%20traceback)

Comment: Thanks for answering an old question with new packages! Still useful 

Answer (score 1):

You could also take a look at Python's builtin function [`locals()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#locals). This will probably work for simple cases, although I'm not sure how robust of a solution it will be. Generally speaking, going from object -> variable name [isn't possible in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1534504/convert-variable-name-to-string/1534553#1534553).

```
import json

dos = 2

def foo():
    uno = 1
    tres = 3

    try:
        json.loads(uno)
    except:
        print locals()

foo()
>>> {'uno': 1, 'tres': 3}
```

Comment: I've seen people use some interactive debug toolbar for django that shows variables in use during the uncaught exception, so I have a feeling it's possible; just can't find it.