# print argument name (str) passed to function from within that function

Tags: python-3.x, function, arguments

let's say I have a function

```
def argname(nr):
    ...
```

and I'd like to have this function print the name (str) of the arg passed when calling it, eg

```
n = 9

argname(n)
```

this should print "n".

Is this somehow possible in Python 3 ?

Comment: The function only receives the value, not the external variable the value was held in.

Comment: No, it's not posssible for `argname` to know it because your variable `n` is replaced by `9` before even `argname` is called.

Comment: You could use the inspect module to look for the place where argname was called and analyse the line of code at that place but that would be painful to implement.

Comment: thank you for those hints. I will have to find a different approach then.

Comment: I found something similar that might be able to help you [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1534504/convert-variable-name-to-string)