# I have to create a new dictionary from two diffrent dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary

I have two dictionaries as d1 and d2. I want to create a new dictionary that I used d1 and d2 as keys on it.

```
d1 = {"open": 10, "close":15}
d2 = {"open":11, "close":14}
```

output:

```
D = {"d1":{"open": 10, "close":15}, "d2":{"open":11, "close":14}}
```

Comment: You do it exactly as you have done in your output.  What's the question?

Comment: You are probably solving the wrong problem, but take a look at the results of `globals()` and `locals()`

Comment: See this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1534504/convert-variable-name-to-string

Answer (score 0):

you can create `D` like so:

```py
D = {"d1":d1, "d2":d2}
```

although if you change the values in either `d1` or `d2` after you define `D`, it will also change the corresponding values in `D` because `D` will have shared references to `d1` and `d2`. if you don't want this you can use copies

```py
D = {"d1":d1.copy(), "d2":d2.copy()}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```
d1 = {"open":10, "close":15}
d2 = {"open":11, "close":14}

def tostr(**kwargs):
    return kwargs

D = tostr(d1=d1, d2=d2)
print(D)

The output is
```

{'d1': {'open': 10, 'close': 15}, 'd2': {'open': 11, 'close': 14}}