# Save dataframes to multiple CSVs retaining dataframe name

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, for-loop

How can I export multiple dataframes to CSVs that have the same title, in general code?

I tried:

```
dframes_list = [economy, finance, language]

for i, df in enumerate(dframes_list, 1):
    filename_attempt1 = "{}.csv".format(i)
    filename_attempt2= f"{i}.csv"
    df.to_save(filename_attempt2)
```

Expected Output:

```
file saved: "economy.csv"
file saved: "finance.csv"
file saved: "language.csv"
```

Comment: How is generated `dframes_list = [economy, finance, language]` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think in python [is strongly not recommended](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1534504/convert-variable-name-to-string) create strings variables, because then generate strings is not [trivial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18425225/getting-the-name-of-a-variable-as-a-string).

Then best is create another list for names in strings and use `zip`:

```
dframes_list = [economy, finance, language]
names = ['economy','finance','language']
for i, df in zip(names, dframes_list):
    filename_attempt1 = "df_{}.csv".format(i)
```

Another idea is create dict of DataFrames:

```
dframes_dict = {'economy': economy, 'finance': finance, 'language': language}
for i, df in dframes_dict.items():
    filename_attempt1 = "df_{}.csv".format(i)
```

If need working with dict of `DataFrame`s use:

```
 for k, v in dframes_dict.items():

     v = v.set_index('date')
     #another code for processing each DataFrame

     dframes_dict[k] = v
```

Comment: Thanks. How do I update the dataframes or at least the dictionary key? If I do ```df = df.set_index('date')``` in the forloop, nothing changes when I run outside the forloop: ```dframes_list['economy']```

Comment: @asd  - Give me a sec.

Comment: @asd - added to answer, you need set fictionary of dfs in last step.

Answer (score 0):

If you're doing this on a notebook, you can use a hack where you search the `locals()` and you could use regex to match 'dframes_list = [.+]` that should return a string value

```
'dframes_list = [economy, finance, language]'
```

which then you can do replacing until you get to 'economy, finance, language' at which point you can split and get a list.

A colab version works like this,

```
temp_local = dict(locals())
data = {}
for k,v in temp_local.items():
  try:
    if re.match('dframes_list = \[.+\]', v):
      data[k] = v
      print(k, v)
  except:
    pass
```

then,

```
names = re.findall('\[.+\]', data[key])[0].replace('[', '').replace(']', '').split(',')
```

where `key` has been identified from the `data` dict.

This isn't recommended tho.