# Can we print the value of a local variable by using its corresponding symbol in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

This is just demo code:

I have say below local variables. Now the `local_variables` method would list them.

```
name = "john"
sex = "M"
age = 20
dob = "12/12/1998"

p local_variables #[:name, :sex, :age, :dob]
```

Can we use those symbols to print the values they have been assigned?

As an example:

```
p name #"john"
```

But I am trying to check if I get the same value "john" using `:name` or not.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get The Name Of A Local Variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3249786/get-the-name-of-a-local-variable)

Comment: @meagar how do you find it out? I searched but didn't anyway thanks! Probably the post subject line is responsible for that. :)

Comment: What do you mean by *"I have say below local variables"*? Do you mean *"I have stay below local variables"* (but that does not make sense either)? Something else? (Respond by [editing your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/15768904/edit), not here in comments (as appropriate).)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `eval`.

```
eval("name") # "john"
```

Comment: `local_variables.each { |s| puts "#{s} = #{eval(s.to_s).inspect}" }` ?

Comment: Note, however, that this is generally "code smell". If you want to store a bunch of named values to retrieve later, use a Hash, not local variables.

Comment: @Phrogz - good point. I think iAmRubuuu is having fun testing some Ruby boundaries, so it's more about "can I" than "should I". I'm learning just by trying to answer them though :-)

Comment: @NeilSlater Yup. Further, it is reasonable to want to use local variables for the appropriate reasons and during debugging perform introspection to get them.

Comment: This is definitely awesome for debugging, especially if you can't use tools like byebug in production.