# Any way to get the title or name of a hash and/or array in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, json, hash

So pretty straight forward but I cant find the answer.

Say I have an object dumped in YAML as such:

```
page: 
  page_url: http://www.stackoverflow.com/
  created_at: "2011-08-10T11:00:19Z"
  website_id: 1
  updated_at: "2011-08-10T11:00:19Z"
  id: 1
Hash
```

I know from the dump that it is a hash by using .class and that the title is page. I can reference any of the keys as you normally would. How on earth do you get the title or name of the hash? and is it the same for arrays?

---

results of object.methods

Hash

```
presence
zip
find_index
invert
silence_stderr
enum_slice
deep_merge
load
gem
require_dependency
extract!
minmax
encode64
rehash
debugger
methods
send
assert_valid_keys
replace
values_at
empty?
group_by
diff
taint
instance_variable_defined?
shift
stringify_keys
take
to_param
to_yaml
key?
find_all
update
silence_stream
as_json
singleton_class
keys
require
many?
min_by
each_cons
entries
to_hash
singleton_methods
instance_eval
require_library_or_gem
to_json
first
require_or_load
nil?
b64encode
take_while
select
deep_merge!
with_options
extractable_options?
exclude?
max_by
enum_cons
deep_symbolize_keys
protected_methods
instance_exec
display
sort
store
returning
tainted?
method
delete_if
include?
stringify_keys!
untaint
instance_of?
merge!
symbolize_keys
drop
equal?
suppress
reject
merge
minmax_by
sum
to_set
yaml_initialize
hash
private_methods
all?
sort_by
default_proc
to_query
silence_warnings
`
require_association
kind_of?
freeze
acts_like?
drop_while
eql?
indexes
html_safe?
collect
id
reverse_merge
slice
reject!
grep
each_value
instance_values
with_warnings
any?
public_methods
breakpoint
symbolize_keys!
object_id
is_a?
has_key?
cycle
indices
to_options
except!
map
member?
tap
type
fetch
with_indifferent_access
each_with_index
decode64
count
each_key
instance_variable_names
enable_warnings
one?
instance_variables
try
__id__
frozen?
suppress_warnings
clear
load_dependency
to_enum
to_yaml_properties
has_value?
to_a
respond_to?
each_with_object
each
taguri
inject
slice!
class
encode_json
reverse_update
length
enum_with_index
instance_variable_get
each_pair
copy_instance_variables_from
none?
taguri=
find
==
__send__
===
enum_for
min
to_options!
extend
value?
to_s
default
index_by
index
size
reduce
blank?
unloadable
to_yaml_style
default=
clone
reverse_each
decode_b
=~
instance_variable_set
detect
values
to_xml
max
each_slice
inspect
[]
class_eval
present?
duplicable?
reverse_merge!
except
partition
delete
[]=
dup
```

---

keys and key cannot be referenced for some reason. observe

```
puts object.keys
```

returns

```
undefined method `keys' for nil:NilClass
```

```
puts object.key
```

returns

```
undefined method `key' for #<Hash:0x103aeb0b0>
```

---

Solution: you guys are gonna hate this. I fixed the problem by running

```
sudo gem update
```

No joke. It updated ruby 1.8.7 to 1.8.7 and that was it. problem solved. I never done anything crazy with my ruby installation but it seems something in there must have messed with the hash. or perhaps it was a very rare bug. I cannot find anything in the update trace that would have caused this. Thanks to everyone who helped.

Comment: and wouldn't you know it. keys is right there

Comment: I think what you're looking for has been answered here: [Ruby - Get a Variable's Name][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/58482/ruby-get-a-variables-name

Comment: I think what you're looking for has been answered here: [Ruby - Get a Variable's Name][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/58482/ruby-get-a-variables-name

Comment: @user688513 The answer to that problem was a bit obscure and doesn't really help in my case. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"page" is just a key in the top-level Hash. You could always just use `Hash#keys` to get the list of top-level names. In your case, it would be just one element, so:

```
x.keys.first == 'page'
=> true
```

Comment: undefined method `keys' for #<Hash:0x103aeb0b0>  Thats weird. Any ideas?

Comment: Did you redefine the Hash class somewhere? What does `object.methods` return?

Comment: @OVERTONE, no, no ideas, `#keys` is available in even quite old versions of Ruby. I am a bit curious; let us know what the final resolution is.

Comment: @Karl Most definitely didn't. Very strange. I've posted the object.methods in the question

Comment: Is there a variable to reference array names in such a way? perhaps if i check the arrays i cant get to the bottom of this

Comment: I see `undefined method 'keys' for nil:NilClass`, is that a hiccup on your part or is it actually nil? As far as array names, arrays are kinda like hashes except the "keys" are just numbers... e.g. `array[0]` would return the first element. So no, there isn't a keys method for arrays.

Comment: also try just typing `object` into the command line so we can see the hash structure.

Comment: @karl. The object is definitely initialised as a hash. when i reference key it shows as a hash. when i reference keys, it shows as nil. It was bizarre. Yours going to hate the solution to the problem though as i have no way of finding out why this happened. I've added the solution to the question.

Comment: Guess it would make sense for it to be a problem with the environment, the code didn't make any sense...

Answer (score 0):

Hashes and Arrays do not have "titles". Hashes have keys. :page is a key in the hash, and object[:page] is also a hash.

You can get all the keys of a hash by calling .keys

```
object.keys
=> [:key1, :key2, :key3]
```

If you are trying to figure out if an object is a Hash or Array, you can call object.kind_of?(Hash), however you most likely shouldn't need to do this.

Comment: I dont need to figure out if they are an array or a hash. Long story short I have a JSON string I've converted into an array which contains multiple other objects. But when I try to check what kind of object they are per their name I have nothing to reference

Comment: Also, object.keys is coming back as an undefined method which is quite strange.