# How to automatically log to console when a variable is changed in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, events, logging, trace

In Ruby I'd like to have a message printed to console whenever a given variable is changed at any time during execution.

How should I approach this? Should I monkey patch the method for assigning values to variables?

I could only find this related question  [Hook to be called when a variable changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8860450/hook-to-be-called-when-a-variable-changes) where an answer is suggesting to redefine #freeze but this approach has limitations. Also it doesn't *look right*.
Isn't there a better and more consistent solution?

Comment: If you have an attribute on an object you can trap all calls via the writer method like `x=`. Do you have some example code?

Answer (score 1):

Add your own getter/setter.

Example:

```
class Person
  def name
     @name
  end
  def name=(s)
     @name=s
     puts 'name has changed!'
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible.

Neither the [`set_trace_func`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Kernel.html#method-i-set_trace_func) nor the [`TracePoint`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/TracePoint.html) API support tracing variable assignments, and …

> Should I monkey patch the method for assigning values to variables?

… such a method does not exist.

Ruby just doesn't consider variables to part of the object-oriented fabric of the program, I guess. Only objects and methods.