# Variable name from Self in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I have a variable lets call it `@foo`. I expect it to be a string so I call `@foo.downcase`. Sometimes it's nil and i'll get this error:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `downcase' for nil:NilClass
    from (irb):4
    from /Users/schneems/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/irb:16:in `<main>
```

What I want to do is write some code to tell me that nil is actually `@foo`

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `downcase' on variable @foo, variable is a nil:NilClass
    from (irb):4
    from /Users/schneems/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/irb:16:in `<main>
```

To do something like this, I would need to get the name of the variable programatically.

**Question:** Is it possible to get the name of a variable programmatically ruby?

I'm looking for something that produces an output like this:

```
@foo.magical_variable_method    #=> '@foo'
bar.magical_variable_method     #=> 'bar'
AweSome.magical_variable_method #=> 'AweSome'
$wat.magical_variable_method    #=> '$wat'
```

I don't want the value of the variable, nor do i care if it is `nil`. I want the human readable name of the variable. Is it possible to get the name of a variable programmatically ruby?

Comment: Can you clarify what you want a bit more? Are you looking for a way to see if `@foo` is `nil`, or looking for a method that will return back all variables that are currently `nil`? Or perhaps something else entirely?

Comment: I updated the question to hopefully be a little more clear, thanks for asking.

Comment: take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/58482/ruby-get-a-variables-name

Comment: It might be pretty difficult in a language without macros. How about switching to a Lisp?

Comment: It is indeed possible I hacked together one potential solution https://gist.github.com/2907252 though things get hairy if you try to make that code reusable since doing so would require having a variable in a method. Maybe someone with some ruby bindingfu could solve that problem.

Answer (score 1):

What you want is kinda mess.

Here's proper way for this task:

```
@foo && @foo.downcase
```

Or you could use rails library:

```
require 'active_support'

@foo.try(:downcase)
```

Comment: That doesn't answer my question at all, thats how to protect against calling a method on a variable that doesn't exist. I want the string out put of "`@foo`" somehow from the variable named `@foo`, if it was named @bar i would want the variable named "`@bar`".

Answer (score 1):

There isn't currently any way to do this.

Variables are just references, not objects themselves. If you use dot notation to call a method, like `downcase`, that method is operating on an object, not a variable. And the object in your example is the singleton `nil`; if `nil` in one place were to have a property assigned to it naming the variable it was assigned to, that same property would apply to all `nil`s.

Even more generally, one object may have many variables/references pointing to it, so there would be no good way of determining which variable name should be saved in the object. **However**, there is some sort of special treatment in Ruby for assigning a class to a constant; in that case, the class object *does* remember the name of the *first* constant it's assigned to, e.g.:

```
$ irb
1.9.3p194 :001 > Foo = Class.new do
1.9.3p194 :002 >   attr_accessor :foo
1.9.3p194 :003?> end
 => Foo 
1.9.3p194 :004 > Bar = Foo
 => Foo 
1.9.3p194 :005 > Foo.name
 => "Foo" 
1.9.3p194 :006 > Bar.name
 => "Foo"
```

Comment: Come to think of it, though, you would think the implementation would be able to keep in memory the name of a variable whose object you sent a message -- just that the object itself wouldn't hold that information. I'm betting the variable name in this case is known by the parser but unknown to the part of Ruby that actually sends messages; but one would have to dig into the source to find out.

Comment: Local variables are generally not kept around. They are just addressed by index into a local variable array. Some implementations also have an optimization where they keep a small number of instance variables in an array directly in the object header, those are also just indexed by number. And of course an optimizing compiler will often eliminate variables altogether.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the instance variable from the symbol with instance_variable_get(:@foo)
which would just give you the value.

But you could do this:

```
puts "I'm gonna call @foo now, people"
some_obj.instance_variable_get(:@foo)
```

You could also do a method_missing hook for the attrs you wanted to watch. Don't create accessor methods for @foo and catch the call in method_missing and forward it to some generic implementation such as instance_variable_get

Untested attempt:

```
def method_missing(method_name, *args)
  super(method_name, *args) unless watched_attributes.include?(method_name)
  attr = ":@#{method_name.to_str}"
  log.debug "Calling watched attribute #{attr}"
  val = instance_variable_get(method_name)
  log.debug "#{attr} was nil omg!" unless val
  val
end
```

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:**  Probably the best way (see mu's comment) is to just make sure you're working with a string:

```
@foo.to_s.downcase
```

You don't need to get the "name" to do this.  You can just use a conditional:

```
# Downcased if @foo's a string, empty string otherwise:
(String === @foo)? @foo.downcase : ''
```

Or, if you're going to be doing this in lots of places, and don't want to have to wrap each one in a conditional, monkey-patch `NilClass` and add a dummy `downcase` method:

```
class NilClass
    def downcase
        return ''
    end
end
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Monkey patching `NilClass` is madness and asking for trouble. If you want to convert `nil` to an empty string then you should `@foo.to_s.downcase` instead, that way people reading the code will at least get a hint that there's something a little special about `@foo`.

Comment: @muistooshort - I'd say it's safer than usual in this case, as it's obvious what `downcase` should return.  Agreed that it's a dangerous path to start down, though...  Anyway, `to_s` is definitely the best, and I'd forgotten all about it (dur).  Fixed now.  Cheers!

Comment: I want the string out put of "`@foo`" somehow from the variable named `@foo`, if it was named `@bar` i would want the variable named "`@bar`". I'm familiar with how to protect against no method errors, what I want is the actual variable name from ruby programmatically, as the question states.