# ruby - how to get string objects name inside loop?

Tags: ruby, loops

`top`, `top_middle`, `bottom_middle` and `bottom` are four long strings.

How can I DRY up the following given that `current`'s string values are the same as the name of the variable being used by `the_line` - but not its actual variable.

Is there some sort of "variable.variable_name" for what it is?

```
[top,top_middle,bottom_middle,bottom].each_with_index do |the_line, i|
  current=
    case i
      when 0 then "top"
      when 1 then "top_middle"
      when 2 then "bottom_middle"
      when 3 then "bottom"
    end
  puts current
  puts the_line
end
```

Output is okay as is:

```
top
 ――      |   ――    ――   |  |   ――   |      ――    ――    ―― 
top_middle
|  |     |   __|   __|  |__|  |__   |__      |  |__|  |__|
bottom_middle
|  |     |  |        |     |     |  |  |     |  |  |     |
bottom
 ――      |   ――    ――      |   ――    ――      |   ――      |
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ruby - Get a Variable's Name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/58482/ruby-get-a-variables-name)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than having each of those related things as separate variables, I'd put the four of them together in a Hash:

```
lines = {
  :top           => ' ――      |   ――    ――   |  |   ――   |      ――    ――    ―― ',
  :top_middle    => '|  |     |   __|   __|  |__|  |__   |__      |  |__|  |__|',
  :bottom_middle => '|  |     |  |        |     |     |  |  |     |  |  |     |',
  :bottom        => ' ――      |   ――    ――      |   ――    ――      |   ――      |'
}
```

That cleans things up nicely:

```
lines.each do |current, the_line|
  puts current
  puts the_line
end
```

This produces:

```
top
 ――      |   ――    ――   |  |   ――   |      ――    ――    ―― 
top_middle
|  |     |   __|   __|  |__|  |__   |__      |  |__|  |__|
bottom_middle
|  |     |  |        |     |     |  |  |     |  |  |     |
bottom
 ――      |   ――    ――      |   ――    ――      |   ――      |
```

(If you really need `current` as a string, you can call `to_s` on it, but leaving it as a symbol is fine in this case.)