# Is it possible to compare Ruby identifiers?

Tags: ruby

Is there a way to compare ***identifiers***?

I know that this sounds super weird and dumb and looks like I'm on drugs, but here goes:

---

First, have some class:

```
class MyClass

end
```

Now, alias that class with two constants:

```
A = MyClass
B = MyClass
```

Obviously `A == B`.

Now, have some operator Ω, which compares *identifiers*:

```
A Ω B       # => False
A Ω MyClass # => False
A Ω A       # => True
```

Another example would be:

```
x = 10
y = 10

x Ω y   # => False
x Ω 10  # => False
x Ω x   # => True
```

Is this possible in Ruby? Is there, perhaps, some sort of meta method that allows you to get the string name of a given identifier?

---

**Practical uses for this**

None. Just curious.

Comment: A and B aren't keywords, they're identifiers. `def` or `class` would be keywords.

Comment: @sepp2k: Thanks, sorry. Edited now.

Comment: @JustKidding Ok, you mean A = B = class. As `MyClass` is class name, not a keyword.

Comment: @JustKidding none of combinations mentioned in your question would return boolean, for class name constants identifier comparison result would be class name A Ω B => MyClass and for variable identifiers comparison as per your post would return x Ω y => 10. It's my guess.

Comment: @AlokAnand: I don't think that I understand. I just want to know if two identifiers have the same name (x and x, A and A, MyClass and MyClass). So ideally Ω is an operator that returns a boolean given two identifiers. MyClass is an identifier too I think (a constant).

Comment: my brain just melted a little. you want to compare variables by their name, not by value?

Comment: Comparing identifiers is easy, getting the identifier from the Object is the hard part. There are many variants of that question on SO, but all of the answers rely on terrible hacks. What you want to do is fundamentally against the design of Ruby.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if identifier is a thing determined by its name, than you have to know how to compare variable's name. Shortly, it is not possible.

Although there are many questions (with great answers) on how to do it. I'd suggest you to take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58482/ruby-get-a-variables-name) one.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your question, you want to know if two identifiers are textually identical. The trivial answer is that this can be determined by inspection of the source. It can also be determined by the interpreter while processing the lexical elements of a statement, but getting at that info is implementation dependent. I suppose one could go looking in the interpreter's symbol table during execution, but I suspect that process is implementation dependent too. I don't know of any standard ruby code for accessing the internal state of the interpreter from within the interpreted program.